# How to compare data frame as a small group in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison, difference

I have two dataframes like this:

```
DF1:

ID     v1           v2         v3
289  1455.0        2.0        0.62239  
289  1460.0        0.0        0.46037  
289  1465.0        4.0        0.41280 
290  1470.0        0.0        0.39540 
290  1475.0        2.0        0.61809 
290  1475.0        2.0        0.61809

DF2:

ID     v1           v2         v3
289  1423.0        2.0        0.62239  
289  142Q.0        0.0        0.46037  
289  14FW.0        4.0        0.41280  
290  14Q3.0        0.0        0.39540  
290  1453.0        2.0        0.61809 
290  1454.0        2.0        0.61809
```

I want to compare the rows which contain the same ID as a whole (i.e: when I compare the first three rows between two df, I don't care about the order of the row, just want to fine the different value), now my method gives me the results of comparing line by line, this may have a problem:

if the 1st row of df1 is the same as the 2nd row of df2,
the 3rd row of df1 is the same as the 1st row of df2,
and the 2nd row of df1 is the same as the 3rd row of df2, this means the first three rows are the same,
but by using my method(comparing line by line), it gives me the difference between each line.

Can someone help me with this? Many thanks.

Here's what I tried and the error:

```
resultBool01 = (DF1 != DF2).stack()  # Create Frame of comparison booleans
resultdiff01 = pd.concat([DF1.stack()[resultBool01], DF2.stack()[resultBool01]], axis=1)
resultdiff01.columns=["output_01", "output_02"]

ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!
```

Expected result:(different values for each ID)

```
ID   difvar  output1     output2
289   v1       1455       1423
```

Comment: What columns are you comparing?  `v1`, `v2`, and `v3`?  What do you expect the results to be?  A pandas series of `True` and `False`?  Even that isn't enough information.  Try to provide a [mcve]

Comment: I want to compare all the variables and print all the differences (not boolean value, I want to print all the different values). I added some codes what I've tried @piRSquared

Comment: Let me know if something like this works: `pd.concat({'DF1': DF1, 'DF2': DF2}).drop_duplicates()`

Comment: Hi I'm new to Python, this gives me wired dataframe with a 'DF1' on the left as index, don't understand at all. @piRSquared

Comment: I understand.  Unfortunately, I won't be able to help unless you provide all the pieces described in a [mcve].  I need to see a complete example of data, not anything with `......` in it.  I need to see what you expect the results to be.  And sample code of what you've tried is a bonus.

Comment: I have edited my question, I added the code I've tried and you can only compare with three variables because my dataset is huge. I just want to compare the first 3 rows between two df instead of comparing them line by line @piRSquared

Comment: That looks good.  Only thing still missing is what you expect the results to look like.

Comment: Print the variable which contain different values for the same ID, I've added in the question too